# Implicit conversion in C89 and C99?

Tags: c, casting

I am reading the book "C programming A modern approach" K.N.King. It is written that implicit conversion happens only if

1. if one operand has type greater that another operand. `(pseudocode) long d + short r`
2. rank of unsigned type of operand is the same or greater that rank of signed operand. `(pseudocode) int a + unsigned int b`
3. signed operand can contain any values of unsigned operand `(pseudocode) long long x + unsigned short y`
4. when we add int to float or long to float. long long to double and so on.

But then I was writing a code and write that

```
int a;
short b=10000 ,c= 150;
a = b * c;
printf("result of product is %d\n", a );
```

I got the right answer 150000. Why? I had two operands of the same type and the implicit conversion didn't have to happen. I didn't use explicit conversion. And interestingly enough, a bit latter it is written that

```
int j  = 1000;
long i = (long) (j * j);
```

This code can produce wrong result on some kind of computers maybe embedded systems, because `j * j` is computed first and the result is **int**, but int can't hold number greater that 500.000 for example and **casting would be late**. I understand that (lateness of the casting) but, in fact, I did the same, but I got another.

Comment: The answer you accepted is incorrect, as acknowledged by the person who posted it. Please unaccept it (click the green check mark again) so it can be deleted.

Comment: I've done it)))

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69600227/827263) describes the *integer promotions*, specified in the standard at [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.3.1.1 paragraph 2. Can you check your book and see whether it actually discusses those conversions? (I don't have King's book, but I've heard good things about it, so I'd be surprised if it didn't mention this.)

Comment: I am on 170 pages. Let me revise some pages again to make sure that there wasn't that.

Comment: It is written in book. But it is written very shortly and not in the enumerated list of implicit conversation, and I didn't give that any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the book says that implicit conversions happen only under those conditions, it is wrong. In integer arithmetic operations (and some others), operands with rank less than `int` or `unsigned int` are converted at least to `int` or `unsigned int`. (The formal rules have additional finicky details.) So, in `b * c`, the `short` operands `b` and `c` are promoted to `int`, and the result type is `int`. The mathematical result, 1,500,000, fits in an `int` in your C implementation, so there is no overflow.